How to get image url from accentuate custom fields in shopify?
I got this weird problem.
I'm using the Accentuate Custom Fields plugin for my shopify store. I do all coding in a local dev environment using the liquid templating and all that stuff. For some reason i can't access any of the properties on the images that i'm uploading. I'm using a repeatable sections that has a text field and a media field.
This is my field setup:

This is my loop to display the fields:
    {% for t in product.metafields.accentuate.image_and_text_text %} 
      {% assign text = t %}
      {% assign img = product.metafields.accentuate.image_and_text_image[forloop.index0] %}

      {{ img }}

      {{ text }}//works

    {% endfor %}

When printing the IMG i get this object:
{"filename"=>"ST72LinkF_Runner-up-Yallingup-Event-Hire.webp", "mime_type"=>"image/webp", "media_type"=>"image", "alt"=>"", "id"=>1723198909694, "key"=>"8563676578042/1723198909694/ST72LinkF_Runner-up-Yallingup-Event-Hire.webp", "scope"=>"8563676578042", "handle"=>"1723198909694", "src"=>"https://cdn.accentuate.io/8563676578042/1723198909694/ST72LinkF_Runner-up-Yallingup-Event-Hire.webp?v=1723198909694", "original_src"=>"https://original.accentuate.io/8563676578042/1723198909694/ST72LinkF_Runner-up-Yallingup-Event-Hire.webp?v=1723198909694", "cloudinary_src"=>"https://cld.accentuate.io/8563676578042/1723198909694/ST72LinkF_Runner-up-Yallingup-Event-Hire.webp?v=1723198909694&options=", "width"=>2302, "height"=>1536, "aspect_ratio"=>1.4986979166666667}

The obvious for me would be to do:
{{ img.src }}

But that gives me nothing, which is really weird. What am i doing wrong here?
